# Bit of paragraph code that's throwing my site positioning off?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm stumped about something, a bit of code that every time I place at the bottom of my site throws my site slightly to the right, which makes it jarring when going from that page to another, you can see the nav panel jumping to the right, etc.

I'm an amatuer at this stuff, designing my own artist website. Any suggestions as to why when I place this in. Appreciate any help!

This is the code causing this shifting:

```
<div class="copyright">
<p>
COPYRIGHT ©2017 WILSON SCHLAMME, ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
</p>
</div>
```

and this is on the css page: *note removing this css still doesn't alleviate the shifting.

```
.copyright {
font-size: 51%;
color: #a6a6a6;
letter-spacing:1px;
padding-bottom:20px;
font-family: "Proxima Nova", Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino,                 
 serif;  
}
```

And this is the entire code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.bio {
  color: #808080;
  line-height: 160%;
  line-spacing: 40%;
  max-width: 700px;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova", Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino, serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 48%;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova", Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino, serif;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  word-spacing: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #bfbfbf;
}

#headerimg {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.spacer1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.spacer2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.spacer3 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.spacer4 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.infoimg img {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 3px #7C7C7C;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 3px #7C7C7C;
  min-width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  border-width: 1px;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.copyright {
  font-size: 51%;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova", Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino, serif;
}

a {
  color: #a6a6a6;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.speech {
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #808080;
  line-height: 160%;
  line-spacing: 40%;
  max-width: 700px;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova", Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino, serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerimg">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="img/headerfont2.PNG" style=" width:28%"> </a>
</div>

<div class="spacer1">

</div>
<div class="w3-container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">VISUAL </a></li>
    <li><a href="info.html">INFO</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="infoimg">
  <img src="img/info.png" style="width:20%">
</div>

<div class="spacer2">

</div>

<div class="bio">
  <p>
    Wilson Schlamme was born in Jackson Mississippi in 1988. He graduated from the USC School of Cinematic Arts in 2010, focusing his studies on photography and visual design. Finding himself dissatisfied with the medium post college, Wilson shifted his work
    into painting, and spent the next several years developing a technique largely derived from fluid based paint and self crafted tools. Wilson currently lives in Los Angeles, where he creates abstract works, continuing the tradition of action painting
    and further progressing his organic and overwhelming fluid like style.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="spacer3">

</div>
<div class="speech">
  <p>
    <i>
    "While the work ranges in severity, it's structured around a succinct visual         
    reaction produced from color and textual blending. This reaction shapes not 
    only the core lines of each piece but is also the vocabulary of the work 
    itself.
    Aggressive blending of this sort (done not with a brush but with a hard 
    edge), combined with a limited color palette, allows for the viewer to feel 
    familiar and secure with the work while at the same time in question over 
    the fervent gestural movements. This polarization of the known yet unknown, 
    similar yet contrasting, is a circumstance that is shared both with the 
    viewer and theartist, and likewise becomes a focal point of shared 
    experience."
    </i>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="spacer4">
</div>

<div class="copyright">
  <p>
    COPYRIGHT ©2017 WILSON SCHLAMME, ALL RIGHTS RESERVED

</div>
```

Comment: Which part of code causes the problem?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. <div class="copyright">
<p>
COPYRIGHT ©2017 WILSON SCHLAMME, ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
</p>
</div>

Comment: Removing it doesn't shift the snippet.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that Achraf. I mean, I've considered just removing it and calling it a day, but I want to have text that says that at the bottom of my page.

Comment: I mean it is not causing any shifting for me here.

Comment: Huh. weird. I'm using chrome right now. Perhaps I'll do more testing on other devices and see if it's...actually something this computer is uniquely doing. thx

Comment: @Masteryogurt looks ok to me, too. removing the `.copyright` element entirely doesn't shift the page.

Comment: @Masteryogurt maybe you should post code from another page of your website to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fixed or absolute positioning. Fixed will keep it on the screen at all times, even during scroll; absolute will scroll:

```
.copyright {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 51%;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova", Palatino Linotype, Book Antiqua, Palatino, serif;
}
```

Note: I removed the padding because of fixing the position.

Note: I wasn't getting the shifting either, however, I am not going back and forth between pages.

The style looks good, just be careful of your color contrast. Be sure it passes accessibility standards so people with low vision are able to read your site.

Comment: Thank you, fixed the shifting. Not sure why that was happening, guess making certain elements fixed/absolute can fix it.